# FindDistributionParameters and Test Options

Tags: probability-or-statistics

This is very much related to my earlier post [FindDistributionParameters and Hypothesis Testing](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/67024/finddistributionparameters-and-hypothesis-testing). However, I did not get a satisfactory anaswer and it keeps bugging me. I am trying to get help this time with an easier example.

I generate some data:

```
data = RandomVariate[WeibullDistribution[1.80631, 421.258],1000];
```

When I run the following code:

```
FindDistributionParameters[data, WeibullDistribution[a, b],
  ParameterEstimator -> "MethodOfMoments"]
```

I get values of $a$ and $b$. I want to test whether $a = 1$ in fitting the data to the Weibull distribution. Can anybody help me please?

Comment: You could perform a parametric bootstrap as explained [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6507/57) and check whether or not the confidence interval around a includes 1.

Comment: @Sjoerd Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: How about `DistributionFitTest[data, WeibullDistribution[1, b]]` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You specifically use the method of moments, is that meant to be a real problem constraint?

If you can instead use the maximum likelihood estimate for `{a,b}` then you can you perform a straightforward likelihood ratio (LR) test. In the following quick check, the LR test statistic is approximately Chi-Square distributed (see Wilk's theorem), so you can accept the null hypothesis that `a=1` unless the test statistic exceeds `InverseCDF[ChiSquareDistribution[1], 1 - \[Alpha]]`.

```
(* Null hypothesis, b is a nuisance parameter *)
H[0] = WeibullDistribution[1, b];

(* Alternative hypothesis, which has one more degree of freedom. *)
H[1] = WeibullDistribution[a, b];

(* Check the distribution of the LR test statistic *)
sampleSize = 100;
lrTestStatistic = Table[
   data = RandomVariate[WeibullDistribution[1, 421.258], 1000];
   sol[0] = FindDistributionParameters[data, H[0]];
   sol[1] = FindDistributionParameters[data, H[1]];
   -2 (LogLikelihood[H[0]/.sol[0], data] - LogLikelihood[H[1]/.sol[1], data]),
   {sampleSize}
];

(* by the eyeball test, I'd say we've met the assumptions for Wilk's theorem to hold *)
\[Alpha] = 0.05;
Plot[{
   CDF[EmpiricalDistribution[lrTestStatistic], x],
   CDF[ChiSquareDistribution[1], x]},
   {x, 0, 2 InverseCDF[ChiSquareDistribution[1], 1 - \[Alpha]]}
]
```

Comment: Thank you Ian for your answer. MM is not my prefer method of estimation. It could be ML too. I think this helps me. Thank you.